# CAMBIAR EL REPOSITORIO GITHUB EN MI PROYECTO EN VSC

Tags: git, vscode, github

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Visual Studio Code, que tenía conectado a un repositorio en GitHub... y no sé por qué motivo, este repositorio cambió, haciendo push me generó un nuevo repositorio en GitHub y nunca más he podido volver al repositorio original... He continuado haciendo cambios en mi proyecto pero no encuentro la manera de volver a tener este proyecto en el repositorio inicial y me haga los cambios... ¿Alguien sabe como modificar el repositorio desde VSC?
Gracias!!!

Comment: Supongo que se trata de que coloques el URL adecuado para el remoto. El URL usando `git remote get-url el-remoto-que-tengo` te da el URL adecuado? Si no es así, modifícalo con `git remote set-url el-remoto-que-tengo el-URL-adecuado`

Comment: no funciona!!!!

Comment: Muestra lo que dice `git remote get-url`, indica cual es el repo que quieres en github, lo que dice `git push`... etc etc

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Si no se modifico la url del remoto  quizás te sirva  ver los commits
> realizados para seleccionar la version que deseas

```
git log --oneline
```

> en mi repo responde

```
4a9a11e (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) added views and controllers
1000a7c added message, thread, user services
fde30cd added user, thread, message models
c5eb425 readme, bootstrap, setup ready
5819c44 initial commit
```

> Si quiero volver a una version inicial  el historial de commits se
> restablece a esa version con este comando

```
git reset --hard c5eb425
```

> Este procedimiento sirve en forma local con un repo remoto compartido
> se complica

Comment: es a un repo remoto..... gracias !!

Comment: si no es compartido no hay problema ..podes usar tambien  checkout diferente a  reset  en éste último se descartan las revisiones, mientras que con checkout se preservan. git checkout <id commit>

Comment: eje c/ un archivo < git checkout 55df4c2 prueba.txt>una vez restaurado el archivo, es necesario volver a añadir el archivo y volver a hacer un “commit” ya que el archivó cambió<.git add prueba.txt>
 <git commit -m 'restaurar prueba.txt al estado del primer commit.'>

Comment: Es remoto compartido !!! Además probé lo que me decias y los commit q me aparecian son unos de prueaba que realicé una vez empezó el fallo....

Comment: en la pagina de github podes ver tambien los cambios en el vinculo explican como https://docs.github.com/es/repositories/working-with-files/using-files/tracking-changes-in-a-file   tambien podes probar este comando en tu terminal para ver mejor los cambios git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all

Comment: tambien tenes este plugin para VSC muy util Git Graph extension for Visual Studio Code

Comment: [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)